# .htaccess REFERER rederect to another page getting The page isn’t redirecting properly

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm using a simple htaccess to when some user land to my site from external specific referrer to my site page redirect him to home page

ex- when user access this from referrer site **http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/nature-wallpaper-06-2560x1600.jpg** i need him to redirect home page  **http://www.example.com** without show image

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://fersite\.biz [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it shows **The page isn’t redirecting properly** on my browser

[image]

I can normally access all pages of site without problem, is someone have idea about fix this issue, my site wordpress

Comment: Why are you appending `$1`, if you say you want to redirect them to the home page? `$1` is exactly the path you matched here to begin with, so unless you are changing to a different domain here, of course this is a redirect loop.

Comment: ops is there anyway to remove referrer and redirect to home, i really need to to avoid download my images directly from external sites visitors

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is a link-attribute rel="no-referrer" set on the referring website.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy

Regards Tom

Comment: <a class="down_ll" href="linkhere" target="_blank" download="">Download Original Size</a> no that link is like this, i haven't access to control it